# SQL Server CE checksum changes on SELECT queries

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, checksum

Why when I only do `SELECT` on a .sdf file, it's checksum changes ?

How can I avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds strange - try to access as read-only - 
@"Data Source =;Mode = Read Only;Temp Path=",